How to get the home tenant ID for a multi-tenant application given its application (client) ID using MS Graph?
Is there a way to get the home tenant ID of a multi-tenant application given its application (client) ID?
I'm using a multi-tenant application in my tenant for which a service principal has been created. Recently, the multi-tenant application stopped working, and I can see that it has an expired client secret.
I want to reach out to the owners of the multi-tenant application, but I don't know how to get the home tenant ID (or domain) of the multi-tenant application.

You could try using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<your_tenants_service_principal_id> which should contain a "appOwnerOrganizationId" that should be the tenant of the original owner.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Thank you. The appOwnerOrganizationId is listed as null. The servicePrincipalType is listed as Legacy. Any ideas? :)

Would you by chance be able to share the login/onboarding URL of the app? These usually contains ID's - which would lead to the origin. Assuming you use OAuth2 to grant access to the app and then retrieve access tokens?

I found it, it's an SharePoint App-Only app-principal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs. The information was conveyed by a colleague. I didn't figure it out by calling MS Graph

Check the property appOwnerOrganizationId of servicePrincipal.
It's the tenant ID where the application is registered.
To get a little bit more info about the tenant by id, you can call
GET /v1.0/tenantRelationships/findTenantInformationByTenantId(tenantId='{tenant_id}')

But it requires the permission CrossTenantInformation.ReadBasic.All
